# Discord.py running commands on a separate thread

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

My discord bot has command that makes the bot it say "I'm running" every 30 seconds. However that makes the main thread sleep making the bot commands unusable.

the code is as follows:

```
    while true:
        await channel.send("I'm running")
        time.sleep(30)
```

I tried using https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/82 and https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe as a reference, but I couldn't understand how it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use some non-blocking sleep. Instead of using `time.sleep` you could for example try `await asyncio.sleep(30)` Maybe it works straight?

If not, then you must implement manual timer to call `channel.send` after certain time has passed with `if` statements for example. Asynchronous methods might be confusing at first.

Examples about threading you checked, are outdated, since discord.py uses async methods nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

If its purpose is only to send a certain message every 30 seconds. You could also create a task which runs every 30 seconds. You can start/stop the task anytime you want.

Example:

```
class example_class():
    def __init__():
        self.channel = None

    async def some_command_starting_our_task(ctx):
        self.channel = ctx.channel
        botStatus.start() # Used to start the task

    async def some_command_stopping_our_task():
        botStatus.stop() # Used to stop the task

    @task.loop(seconds=30)
    async def botStatus():
        self.channel.send("Im running")
```

For more information about tasks you can read the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/).